# HTML5 Audio Player Delete Buffer after played

Tags: html, html5-audio

I have a simple HTML5 Audio player on my website like this:

```
<audio src="file.ogg" preload="none" loop="loop" controls="controls" >
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio >
```

I want that if the file was played to end the file should be reloaded. now if the file is played and I click on play again it plays the file which is in the clients browser cache. but I want if I click play the file should be loaded again from the browser.

Answer (score 1):

You really cant.

What you can do is. that is what I would do at least .embed a js to be triggered when you hit play button(just a play image not the actual file) that should create a new audio tag. 
that way it creates a new audio. Audio is super limited.

No way to control buffering, there was a flag at somepoint to disable the buffering they removed it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have, for example, "stopped" the media with:

```
media.pause();
media.currentTime = 0;
//Just reload
media.load();
```

That should clear the buffer.